# Evaluate clustering accuracy based on an adjacency/similarity/connection matrix

Tags: classification, clustering, model-evaluation, accuracy, permutation

## Description

In the classification tasks, the classification accuracy is computed by

```py
accuracy=n_correct/n_total
```

For example, if I have three samples, and the ground truth labels are `[0,1,0]` and the predicted labels are `[0,1,1]`, then the accuracy will be `2/3=0.667`.

In clustering, since label names do not matter that we only care about the relationships among samples, I wonder if there is a connection-matrix-based method that is commonly used in the machine learning world.

```py
import numpy as np


def custom_accuracy(expected, pred):
    # ignore diagonal elements
    return (np.sum(expected == pred) - expected.shape[0]) / (expected.size - expected.shape[0])


def generate_connection_matrix(labels):
    labels = labels.flatten()
    left_matrix = np.repeat(labels.reshape(-1, 1), len(labels), axis=1)
    return np.equal(left_matrix, labels).astype(np.float32)


y_true = np.array([0, 10, 13, 4, 1, 5, 7, 3, 6, 12, 9, 8, 2, 9, 15, 3, 9, 10, 11, 14]).astype(np.int64)
y_pred=np.array([12, 10, 14, 6, 15, 9, 5, 3, 5, 5, 8, 13, 9, 4, 9, 7, 0, 11, 1, 2]).astype(np.int64)
acc = custom_accuracy(generate_connection_matrix(y_true), generate_connection_matrix(y_pred))
print(acc)
```

The output shows

```
0.9421052631578948
```

## Problem

So far the connection matrix version seems reasonable, however, when I compare it to the best-permutation one, I get a confusing result. I compute all permutations of `y_pred` and find the following permutation is the best compared to `y_true`. If I use the same evaluation method in the classification, I have

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_true = np.array([0, 10, 13, 4, 1, 5, 7, 3, 6, 12, 9, 8, 2, 9, 15, 3, 9, 10, 11, 14]).astype(np.int64)

y_best=np.array([0, 10, 13, 4, 1, 5, 6, 3, 6, 6, 12, 8, 5, 15, 5, 2, 9, 7, 11, 14]).astype(np.int64)

print(accuracy_score(y_true,y_best))
```

The output shows

```
0.6
```

Now my question is: which result should I trust? 0.94 or 0.6?

Comment: You've given only code. Will you show how connection matrix looks like, and what it is?

Comment: You should definitely look into existing similarity measures like the _adjusted mutual information_ or the _adjusted Rand index_ for computing these similarities.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks. The unadjusted Rand Index is exactly what I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unadjusted [Rand index](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#rand-index) is what I described.

In the above sklearn link, the unadjusted Rand index is given by
$$
RI = \frac{a+b}{C_{2}^{n_{sample}}}
$$
where a is the number of correct 1s, and b is the number of correct 0s. Here, a correct 1 means two samples are in the same cluster and the corresponding element in the connection matrix is 1; a correct 0 means two samples are in different clusters and the corresponding element is 0. $C_{2}^{n_{sample}}$ is the number of pairs, which is $n^{2}$. The `custom_accuracy` function generates the same matrix when computing RI.

Comment: Yes, the Rand index has some theoretical flaws that are corrected by the adjustment. You should prefer the adjusted version. It’s easy to find implementations in common packages, so there’s little friction.